# Protect Spring container from object replacing in grails

Tags: java, spring, security, grails

Java Spring is a agile and powerfull framework. But I try to find some information how to protect object instances inside spring container.

Situation is: I have some grails services, java classes and simple configuration parameters (Boolean, Integer, ...) in spring container (dsl or xml config). I want to know in code that I use exactly the same object that I configured.

Any ideas how to complicate object replacing in spring container?